# Effective Designs for outdoor clothing elevator free from walls

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, torque, pulleys

A strange question, but I live in a building (gringo in Mexico City) where the only area you can dry clothes is in a set of chain-link cubes on the roof. However, those cubes are about a story and a half above the floor. The staircase you have to get to the roof to get to those cubes is steep (see attachment), because the wall was not fully removed, so requires a very steep angle for the stairs.. We have people in our building who are between the ages of 80 and 90 years old and the staircase itself is incredibly poorly designed & very steep and I’m wondering if anyone has any advice on building a pulley or elevator system of some sort could be operated by someone with your very little physical strength… **man I don’t want I don’t want my neighbor to die doing laundry**. I have to hold the hand rails desperately on the East up and dodge hitting my head, which I can only do because My bad for wet laundry has a back strap.

Weight requirements are just based on a very heavy laundry load (let’s assume it will be abused).

Help???

Comment: There are lift chairs for the elderly. In the US they cost around $2000-3000.

Comment: *see attachment*?

Comment: There's some 12V (and maybe 24V) worm geared motors out of China that are/were advertised for clotheslines.